# Managed library / component / api for Windows Mobile WiFi management and control?

Tags: networking, windows-mobile, compact-framework, wifi, zeroconf

Does anyone know of a commercial or free .NET CF library/component/api that I can use within my Windows Mobile 6 and .NET CF 3.5 application?

I need to: enumerate the list of available WiFi networks in range, connect and disconnect specific SSIDs/networks in the list, and manage switching between SSIDs programatically (e.g. I'm currently connected to "public1" and want to switch to "public2" to do some stuff, and then switch back to "public1").

I have tried the OpenNETCF library for this and it somewhat works, but it's crashing quite often with Native Exceptions, which I can't handle with a catch() in my C# code so they bubble up to the end user and they get a nasty windows crash screen with the "send" and "don't send" buttons.

OpenNETCF forums seem to be dead, with lots of posts but no replies to most of them, and the last release from those guys was way back in March 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Last I remember the OpenNETCF code was decent and worked without any issues on a number of devices I tried it on. I certainly don't remember getting native exceptions from it.
Is it possible that you're working on a customised platform? It is possible that the real issue might be due to modifications made to your particular device / operating system.

IIRC we eventually switched to Summit cards for hardware or cost reasons which uses a different API but obviously an API that would only work with Summit cards.

I'm afraid I don't know of any other alternatives atm. Sorry. :(